# Same number of a's and b's but never more than three more of one letter than the other when reading left to right

Tags: regex, finite-automata, state-machine

Could I get a hint on how to construct a regular expression for the alphabet {a, b} which accepts all strings that:

1. Have the same number of `a`'s and `b`'s.
2. Reading the string from left to right, the difference between the number of `a`'s and `b`'s never gets bigger than two.

For example:

- `aaa` is not a valid (because there are 3 `a`'s more than `b`'s)
- `aa` is not valid (not same number of `a`'s and `b`'s)
- `aababb` is valid (same number of `a`'s and `b`'s, and cumulative number of `a`'s or `b`'s is never three more than the other)
- [empty string] is valid
- `bbaabbaa` is valid

Comment: Do you absolutely need a regex for this?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be possible if only the first constraint (`have the same number of a's and b's`) was there. Because of the second constraint there is a solution to your problem.

It's easier to first think of the finite automaton that does your work (I leave this to you as an exercise) and then transform it to a regular expression.

The transformed regex would be:
`[ (((a | (aab) (ab)*) b)* (((b | bba) (ba)*) a)* ]*` (perhaps it can be simplified, also left for you as an exercise).

Comment: "Wouldn't be possible"? What about balancing groups?